# php each array key into strng if child arrays add that key to the parent key

Tags: php, arrays, json

I created the following code to loop throu json data and put al the keys in a single array so I can reference them later on. Ìt does what I need but it's not optimized and there should be aa far better way to implement this in a function.
the json data changes al the time for different types. In the example I use the json data from a categorie source.

I tried two dirrect ways to implement this with a function that I can reuse instead retyping this code all the time.
- function that recalls itself if the value is an array
- passing reference to fuinction
but I failed to get it to work.

My question is if someone give me advies on this and what topic I should learn to get an understand of this.

```
{
    "categories": {
        "0": {
            "@attributes": { 
                "category_id": "2" 
            },
            "category_id": "2",
            "parent_id": "1",
            "categories_name": "Dutch name",
            "isActive": 1,
            "categories_image": "",
            "categories_image_alt": "",
            "sort_order": "1",
            "date_added": "01-07-2014",
            "last_modified": "30-01-2017",
            "categories_name_languages": { 
                "dutch": { 
                    "name":  "Dutch name"  
                } 
            },
            "description": { 
                "dutch": { 
                    "above": { 
                        "@cdata": ""  
                    }, 
                    "below": { 
                        "@cdata": ""  
                    }
                } 
            },
            "meta": {
                "dutch": {
                    "url": "dutch-url",
                    "title": "meta dutch title string" 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
$mapping = array();
foreach ($jsonResult['categories'][0] as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
            if(is_array($value2)) {
                foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                    if(is_array($value3)) {
                        foreach ($value3 as $key4 => $value4) {
                            if(is_array($value4)) {
                                $mapping[] = $value4;
                            }else {
                                $mapping[] = '[\''. $key . '\'][\'' . $key2 . '\'][\'' . $key3 . '\'][\'' . $key4  . '\']';
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        $mapping[] =  '[\''. $key . '\'][\'' . $key2 . '\'][\'' . $key3 . '\']';
                    }
                }
            }else {
                $mapping[] =  '[\''. $key . '\'][\'' . $key2 . '\']';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $mapping[] =  '[\''. $key . '\']';
    }
}
```

and the result is:

```
(
    [0] => ['@attributes']['category_id']
    [1] => ['category_id']
    [2] => ['parent_id']
    [3] => ['categories_name']
    [4] => ['isActive']
    [5] => ['categories_image']
    [6] => ['categories_image_alt']
    [6] => ['sort_order']
    [8] => ['date_added']
    [9] => ['last_modified']
    [10] => ['categories_name_languages']['dutch']['name']
    [11] => ['description']['dutch']['above']['@cdata']
    [12] => ['description']['dutch']['below']['@cdata']
    [13] => ['meta']['dutch']['url']
    [14] => ['meta']['dutch']['title']
)
```

Then everytime if I with json based categories I can load this mapping and know exactly where to get a value from a multiarray.

Added code @Barmar

```
function mapArray($arr) {
    $output = [];
    $map = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach(mapArray($value) as $flattenKey => $flattenValue) {
                $output["${key}][${flattenKey}"] = "['${key}']['${flattenKey}']";
                $map[] = "['${key}']['${flattenKey}']";
            }
        } else {
            $output[$key] = $key;
            $map[] = $key;
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

New output:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes][category_id] => ['@attributes']['category_id']
    [category_id] => category_id
    [parent_id] => parent_id
    [categories_name] => categories_name
    [isActive] => isActive
    [categories_image] => categories_image
    [categories_image_alt] => categories_image_alt
    [sort_order] => sort_order
    [date_added] => date_added
    [last_modified] => last_modified
    [categories_name_languages][dutch][name] => ['categories_name_languages']['dutch][name']
    [description][dutch][aboveProducts][@cdata] => ['description']['dutch][aboveProducts][@cdata']
    [description][dutch][belowProducts][@cdata] => ['description']['dutch][belowProducts][@cdata']
    [meta][dutch][categories_seo_url] => ['meta']['dutch][categories_seo_url']
    [meta][dutch][categories_meta_title] => ['meta']['dutch][categories_meta_title']
)
```

output $map:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ['@attributes']['0']
    [1] => category_id
    [2] => parent_id
    [3] => categories_name
    [4] => isActive
    [5] => categories_image
    [6] => categories_image_alt
    [7] => sort_order
    [8] => date_added
    [9] => last_modified
    [10] => ['categories_name_languages']['0']
    [11] => ['description']['0']
    [12] => ['description']['1']
    [13] => ['meta']['0']
    [14] => ['meta']['1']
)
```

Comment: Use recursion instead of hard-coding the nested loops.

Comment: @Bamer The example you provided flattens the keynames and sets them as an key itself in the array.I tried adjusting the code to get the desired output but I am stuck there.

see added code in my post. 

I need to store the flatten keynames as a value in a single array.

Comment: Just use `array_keys()` on the result.

Comment: I don't see any added code in your post.

Comment: @Barmer sorry was still typing it.

array_keys() works perfect but it's calling an php array function afterwards. Should it not be possible to do this while running the function itself directly?

Comment: Return `$map` instead of `$output`.

Comment: That doesn't work aswell, see post for the output of $map.

Comment: Why did you add that variable then? It's not in the code in the duplicate question. Do what I said before, use `array_keys()` on the result.

Comment: What is `mapArray23`? The name of your function is just `mapArray`

Comment: @Barmer: Sorry I copied the function multiple times but when I posted the code I named the function back to mapArray but forgot to edit the function name within the function itself.

The function names with my php test files are named correctly